# Using Iframe as a parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a Iframe with loads a form within it. When I click on the submit button (in the form within Iframe), I wish to load the response within the parent window (making the iframe as the parent window)

Any ideas on how to go with it

Comment: iframe as parent? huh? Not understanding what you are trying to do. When you submit the form in the iframe, you want it to load in the iframe or the parent window?

Comment: I mean, making Iframe as the parent window (the entire content of Iframe within its parent window)

Comment: when you submit the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the form's target to _top.

```
<form target="_top" action="#" method="get">
```

The form submission will replace the iframe's parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to the the parent window via "parent" property. And call functions from there if you need to do some special scripting. Otherwise I much prefer @epascarello's solution.